# Why my first load data axios is return 404 Vue Js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

so guys I've tried to fetch data and show it inside my component. But the problem is, fetching data got `404` or data not show for the first load.. but when I try to reload again data is shown as should be. And one thing.. the data was success upload to the server even the response status `404` as I said

By the way guys this is my **component.js**

```js
getApi() {
  return api.get("/routeName")
}
```

this is my **Store**

```js
async fetchApi({ commit }) {
  try {
    let {
      data: { data }
    } = await component.getApi()
    commit("SET_API", data)
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error)
  }
}
```

and this is how I call `fetchApi` from a store inside my component

```js
async created() {
  await this.getApi()
}

methods: {
  async getDraft() {
    try {
      await this.$store.dispatch("component/fetchApi")
      this.scrollToTop()
    } catch (error) {
      error
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The provided code LGTM. Try to debug the whole thing by doing two things: 1. check the network tab (browser devtools) and see why you do have a 404 (check the response and the payload that you do send, maybe missing something there) 2. check the vuex mutation and what does it contain. Leave the refresh aside since it's not a real way around. Also, do you have some logic to load your components or some asynchronicity ?

Comment: The Vue 'created' hook is not async. [Can’t get created hook to work when it’s async](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/cant-get-created-hook-to-work-when-its-async/28604)

Comment: @kissu Thanks for the answer. make sense, but about the logic.. what do you mean about logic in components? Thanks

Comment: and Hi @kissu, I've tried to see my store, I now know, that the problem starts when promises don't get data from `await reviewClient.getDraft()`. I tried to console.log

Comment: You have to use `mounted` instead of `created`

Comment: Hi @Mr.Perfectionist thanks for the answer but I've tried `beforeMount()` and `mounted()` but I got the same result

Comment: Then you can use `this.$store.dispatch("review/fetchDraft")` inside `beforeMount()` and `this.getDraft()` in `mounted()`. Remove async await.

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist Isn't it too redundant?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist I've tried your suggestions, but still like before. I don't know what's wrong with my code.. oh yea.. by the way.. this page/component load by router push from another page

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist like this

`if (this.step === this.total_step) {
   this.$router.push({ name: "PreviewOnlineReview" })
   return
}`

Comment: What do you have in your vue devtools (is you data populated) ? Also, what do you see in the network tab (the reason of the `404`) ?

Comment: Because you get a 404 from the api, I think your problem is not in your client javascript, but the problem exists in the api response of `/reviews/draft`?

Comment: @Tim I don't see any problem in using an `async created` hook. I mean, it's not going to wait for any async requests to complete but you can still use it for the `await` syntax

Answer (score -1):

I assume you access VUEX state data in `<template>` tag (I cannot comment to get more information.)

If I right, the problem is compoent not watch VUEX state when data null while you access.

If you render when VUEX state data is null, when data update while you call fetchDraft in yours store. In component not track your VUEX. I don't know why it happen in low level.

In my case, I need to use setInterval to load Vuex state to local data in component. And use it instead of access direct to vuex.

ex.

```
created() {
  this.intervalUpdate = setInterval(() => {
      this.updateData();
    }, 1000);
},

destroyed() {
  clearInterval(this.intervalUpdate);
},

methods: {
  async updateData() {
    this.draftData = await this.$store.dispatch("review/fetchDraft");
  }
}
```

It's not the best solution. But its help me to solve problem that component